# Sending SMS with Intent not working in Oreo 8.1 Google API emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am using this code to send sms:

**This code could be found in many tutorials but it is not working in Oreo, i have sent the correct answer**

```
public void sendSms(String phone) {
        if(null != phone) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");//<-- maybe problem is here
            i.putExtra("address", phone);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.sms)));
        }
    }
```

I have tested this code **in Android 4 to Android 6 and no problem but in Android 8.1 google api emulator says no app can perform this action**, but this emulator **already has SMS app installed**

Also i do not know if this is working in real devices with Oreo 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i found the answer myself:

```
public void sendSms(String phone, String sms) {
        if(null != phone) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto: " + phone));
            i.putExtra("sms_body", sms);
            if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "SMS App not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: is there is a way to go to message application without setting phone number?

Comment: it doesn't work with me, but I found another solution, I'll post it right now

Answer (score 6):

If you want the user to go to send SMS without typing phone number in this part
`Uri.parse("smsto: " + phone)` and let him choose the contact before going to send SMS in Oreo , you can use this code for Oreo and lower versions :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "your message");

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
       sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");           

context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: the only different between `if` and `else` is `setType` in else clause. do you test if clause for lower Oreo versions maybe it also work for lower versions.

Comment: @WIZARD you're right , it works in all versions .. I edited the answer ,thank you

Comment: @WIZARD , in lower versions it shows apphChooser and I want to go direct to send SMS

Comment: a fast answer is adding these lines `if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)  smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");` to your answer